# How to select the device to cast from popup in capybara, selenium, Ruby in chrome

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am trying to select the first device from popup to cast using selenium, capybara but I am not able to do it. Please find the popup below

[image]

I have tried following and it does not seem to be working

```
popup = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last
page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(popup)


page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text
```

Please provide sugggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can't - that's a system dialog and selenium can't interact with it once opened. It MAY be possible to set a default to launch and prevent the dialog from opening via chrome command line switches but I'm afraid I don't know what that would be.